# Is it possible for makefile to move all built objects to dist directory automatically?

Tags: c, makefile

Consider the following scenario

```
# Link to executable
result: file1.o file2.o
    gcc dist/file1.o dist/file2.o -o dist/result23

# Assemble to .o object files
file1.o:    file1.s
    gcc -c dist/file1.s
    mv file1.o dist

file2.o:    file2.s
    gcc -c dist/file2.s
    mv file2.o dist

# Compile to .s assembly files
file1.s:    file1.c
    gcc -S file1.c
    mv file1.s dist

file2.s:    file2.c
    gcc -S file2.c
    mv file2.s dist
```

You'll notice that after each phase, I `mv $some_file dist`. Is it possible to globally declare "once done, move result to dist directory"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such general rule for Makefiles because it would defeat the purpose of the Makefile. By moving away the target file, you force its (unnecessary) remake on the next run of make.

The normal idiom is `all` and `install` here: The `all` target builds all targets in the current build tree, and the `install` target copies them to their final destinations.

If you are trying to keep certain directories (e.g. the source directory) free of generated files, the keywords "out of tree build" will give you good hints.

Comment: Could you provide an example using `all` and `install` please?

Comment: @JAM: [Felix Crux wrote a nice article about creating a basic Makefile.](http://www.felixcrux.com/posts/creating-basic-makefile/)